Need help generating digital signature in xml for aadhar otp generation
I am trying to build a adhaar OTP verification module in salesforce. I have gone through all the resources for the public sandbox and built a piece but now I am stuck at the signature portion of xml. I am not sure how to use the public certificate available in uidai platform to generate the digital signature that can be added to xml.
My current xml without the signature gives a Proxy error
The code I am using is:
@future(Callout = true)
        public static void generateOTP(String aadhaarNumber) {
        String apiUrl = 'callout:UIDAI/otp/2.5/public/9/9/MFoSig475ZNf8Fex6pRZJvHLubNTxkmJDqa4sUYQ1On-CyRk1ZUa6VM';
        String txnId = 'TXN_' + Datetime.now().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss') + String.valueOf(Math.random()).substring(2, 10);
            
        String xmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>' +
            '<Otp uid="999941057058" ac="public" sa="public" ver="2.5" txn="' + txnId + '" ts="' + Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss') + '" lk="MG_g7jJVYUIW7cLYXY5yaqKD6D1TuhjTJdQRRKP1qALVyORrG1pf0QU" type="A">' +
            '<Opts ch="01"/>' +
            '<Signature>Data</Signature>'+
            '</Otp>';

        // Make HTTP request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(apiUrl);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        req.setBody(xmlBody);
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.debug('OTP request successful: ' + res.getBody());
        } else {
            System.debug('Error: ' + res.getStatus());
            System.debug('Response: ' + res.getBody());
        }

I have converted the .cer file to keystore and uploaded in named credential but I am getting the error 08:35:57:178 FATAL_ERROR System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable".
Any advice will be welcome. Thanks a lot!!
